# Deny from all except when the request is actually a sub-request

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using PHP's [virtual()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) function to perform a sub-request to Apache, in order initiate a file download (the files can be heavy, so I can't use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)). The files in question are stored in a non-public directory, since the user's permissions need to be checked before allowing a download.

My project is structured as follows:

```
project/
    .htaccess     -----> rewrite everything to index.php
    index.php     -----> framework + application logic + permissions check
    private/
        .htaccess -----> deny from all
        ...       -----> private files
```

The first problem I encountered was that the sub-request generated by virtual() was getting rewritten by the first .htaccess, so the download never started. This was easy to fix, since there is a [[NS] (no sub-request)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html) rewrite flag that allows not to rewrite URLs in such cases:

```
...
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NS]
...
```

But I still can't make it work because of the other .htaccess (deny from all), that simply rejects all requests and sub-requests.

**The question: is there any way to configure .htaccess to deny access from all, except when the request is actually a sub-request coming from the server itself?**

Comment: Why don't you try `order deny, allow deny from all allow from server ip`?

Comment: I've just tried it and it didn't work. I read somewhere that sub-requests are actually made with the IP address of the client (that would explain why this doesn't work).

Comment: This is an interesting problem +1

Comment: The user comments in the PHP manual often provide useful additional information … http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php#67945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a very interesting problem. Had to dig a bit to figure it out.

You can utilize **[apache_setenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php)** function here.

Have this PHP code before `virtual` call:

```
apache_setenv('internal', '1');  // sets an Apache var with name internal
virtual ( "/private/file.txt" ); // example sub request
exit;
```

Now inside `/private/.htaccess` have this snippet:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=internal
```

This will **deny** all requests except when it there is an `env` variable `internal` is set to `1`. That internal variable is only getting set in your PHP code hence only sub-requests will be allowed and all others will be denied.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I could solve the problem. However, I had to remove the line "Satisfy any" (with it, Apache was giving access to any request, with or without the environment variable being set). Can you re-check this? Also, edit your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes `Satisfy any` isn't really needed. Answer edited.